# Manage translation fields in symfony form type generated with KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors and Translatable

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, bundle, symfony-forms

I'm new to Symfony and I'm using version 2.6

I wanted to create a translation for my products following https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#translatable

I ended up with:

```
<?php

namespace KhaliBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Product
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"name"}, updatable=false)
     * @ORM\Column(length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="smallint", length=1)
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set slug
     *
     * @param string $slug
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setSlug($slug)
    {
        $this->slug = $slug;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get slug
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSlug()
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

    /**
     * Set status
     *
     * @param integer $status
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get status
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param \KhaliBundle\Entity\Category $category
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setCategory(\KhaliBundle\Entity\Category $category = null)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return \KhaliBundle\Entity\Category
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function __call($method, $arguments)
    {
        return $this->proxyCurrentLocaleTranslation($method, $arguments);
    }
}
```

and the ProductTranslation.php file

```
<?php

namespace KhaliBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Knp\DoctrineBehaviors\Model as ORMBehaviors;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_translations")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ProductTranslation
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return ProductTranslation
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return ProductTranslation
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }
}
```

and the ProductType.php

```
<?php

namespace KhaliBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('slug')
            ->add('status')
            ->add('category')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'KhaliBundle\Entity\Product'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'khalibundle_product';
    }
}
```

But I got an exception:

```
Neither the property "name" nor one of the methods "getName()", "name()", "isName()", "hasName()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "KhaliBundle\Entity\Product".
```

Comment: Have you considered to use [a2lix/TranslationFormBundle](https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle) to manage translations togheter with KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors#translatable? It saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer based on comments.

To not reinvent the wheel you can consider to manage translations created using the `KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors` library with it's `translatable` behavior togheter with the [a2lix/TranslationFormBundle](https://github.com/a2lix/TranslationFormBundle). It saves a lot of time because have already  implemented the most common functionalities and it's simply to use.